# sed: Replacing each character individually between delimiters

Tags: batch-file, sed

I'm using a compiler for an old gaming console, but this compiler only accepts ANSI characters. This is a problem because the game is in Japanese, which requires UTF-8. As a workaround, I wrote a batch script that executes sed to replace every Japanese character in the document with its equivalent byte value in hexadecimal.

The main sed script looks like this:

```
chcp 1252
sed "s|\[terminator\]|,$FF|g"^
;"s|ャ|,$00|g"^
;"s|ィ|,$01|g" ^
test.asm > test2.asm
```

So a string like "ャィャ[terminator]" will be converted to ",$00,$01,$00,$FF".

The problem is that non-Japanese characters that can be inserted into a text string, such as digits and punctuation signs, are also used everywhere else in the code, so I had to resort to alternate versions of these characters to prevent sed from converting, say, the semicolon before every comment, which would make the compilation process fail. But this workaround forces the user into copying and pasting each of these alternate characters into whichever string they feel like modifying, instead of just typing them like they normally would.

So, my question is, how can I tell sed to only replace the characters between the string delimiters (pipes) instead of performing the substitutions everywhere in the document?

In other words, I want sed to replace something that looks like this:

```
<label> dw $1234 : db |ャィャ[terminator]|     ; Comment (blah ャィャ blah)
```

to this (pipes and leading comma will be removed afterward):

```
<label> dw $1234 : db |,$00,$01,$00,$FF|     ; Comment (blah ャィャ blah)
```

Notice the comment part is left untouched.

Comment: You should edit your question. Noone seems to understand it, or someone would already have answered. That part is confusing: "But I'd like to go with the more user-friendly approach of keeping the strings within the original document"

Comment: Done. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: For sure. You even got a reply for what it could have become a tumbleweed question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a way to do this in `sed`; but it's going to be complex and challenging to maintain. My suggestion would be to swich to a different language, where this is easy. Here's Awk:

```
awk -F '|' '{ gsub(/\[terminator]/, "$FF", $2);
    gsub(/ャ/, ",$00", $2);
    gsub(/ィ/, ",$01", $2); } 1' test.asm >test2.asm
```

I am on Unix, where single quotes make the most sense here. I understand CMD prefers double quotes, which complicates matters; in the worst case, maybe put the script in a file, and call it with `awk -F "|" -f scriptfile.awk test.asm >test2.asm`

If you don't have Awk for your platform, this should be similarly easy in Perl, Python, or Ruby. (Perl even comes with `a2p` for translating Awk scripts to Perl.)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working after removing the colon at the very end, by replacing the single quotes with double quotes, and by escaping the double quotes.

Comment: Fixed the colon typo; thanks for notifying, and thanks for the accept!

Comment: I've noticed you only escaped the opening square bracket, but not the closing one. Is this another typo, or does it make no difference?

Comment: It's not a typo; thanks for asking. The close bracket is often escaped just like the opening one, but escaping it is redundant, as a lone closing bracket has no special meaning. In a character class, it closes the opening bracket which starts the character class, but that's adifferent story.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo \
   '<address> dw $1234 : db |ャィャ[terminator]|     ; Comment (blah ャィャ blah)' | \
sed    's/\[terminator\]/,$FF/;
    :c1 s/ャ\(.*\)|/,$00\1|/;t c1;
    :c2 s/ィ\(.*\)|/,$01\1|/;t c2'
```

Output:

```
<address> dw $1234 : db |,$00,$01,$00,$FF|     ; Comment (blah ャィャ blah)
```

If counted LABEL names like "*c1*, *c2*, seem like a bother, those *katakana* can also serve as unique LABELs:

```
sed    's/\[terminator\]/,$FF/;
    :ャ s/ャ\(.*\)|/,$00\1|/;t ャ;
    :ィ s/ィ\(.*\)|/,$01\1|/;t ィ'
```

---

Notes.  It seems like the **g***lobal* option of **s***earch* should have worked:

```
echo abcdabcdabcd | sed 's/a/-/g'
-bcd-bcd-bcd
```

Add a *wildcard*, and **g***lobal* doesn't help, it only replaces *one* "a" with a "-":

```
echo abcdabcdabcd | sed 's/a\(.*\)/-\1/g'
-bcdabcdabcd
```

A loop works:

```
echo abcdabcdabcd | sed ':c1 s/a\(.*\)/-\1/;t c1'
-bcd-bcd-bcd
```

Comment: @triplee, please be more specific if you've identified a bug.   At present your comment seems a bit puzzling, since the example output confirms that 1) the given answer avoids comments, and 2) copes with duplicate katakana.

Comment: My bad, I seem to have screwed something up when I tested it.  Removed my comment.  Sorry about that.

Comment: agc: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up accepting tripleee's because it seemed faster in execution, but was tempted to accept yours because I did originally ask for a sed-specific solution.